# Looping in Racket Exercise

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to do an exercise in chapter 3 exercise 45 in the 2nd edition of *How to Design Programs* ([HTDP](https://htdp.org/2021-3-8/Book/index.html)).

So the exercise wants me to make an image of a cat go out one side of the scene and reappear on the starting side. Basically in a loop. I've been stuck on this exercise for more than a week and can't seem to get the logic right. I've searched everywhere for different perspectives, so I don't have to ask for advice, but I'm stuck. I want to finish the exercise, so I can learn from it.

```lisp
(require 2htdp/batch-io)
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)

(define cat1 . )

(define WIDTH  300)
(define HEIGHT 100)
(define RESTART-POINT (+ WIDTH (image-width cat1)))
(define BACKGROUND (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT))
(define cat1-CENTER-TO-TOP
  (- HEIGHT (/ (image-height cat1) 2)))

(define Y-cat1 cat1-CENTER-TO-TOP)

(define cat1-CENTER-TO-WIDTH
  (/ (image-width cat1) 2))

(define (main x0)
  (big-bang x0
    [on-tick tock]
    [to-draw render]))

(define (tock x)
  (+ x 3))

#old version
(define (render x)
  (cond
    [(>= (tock x)  RESTART-POINT)
      (place-image cat1 (tock(-  (tock x) (tock x))) Y-cat1 BACKGROUND)]
    [(<= (tock x) RESTART-POINT)
    (place-image cat1 (tock x) Y-cat1 BACKGROUND)]))
#new version
(define (render x)
  (cond
    [(< (tock x)  RESTART-POINT)
     (place-image cat1 (tock x) Y-cat1 BACKGROUND)]
    [(>= (tock x) RESTART-POINT)
    (place-image cat1 (modulo(tock x)RESTART-POINT) Y-cat1 BACKGROUND)]))
```

This runs the pic of a cat across the screen, but the cat never reappears on the left side like I want it to.

Comment: I think you meant exercise 45, btw. Where are you telling it to go back to the starting point? Are you familiar with what [modulo](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=modulo#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._modulo%29%29) does? In theory, this should be a simple modification of your `tock` function.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thanks for the tip. I was able to make it loop. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @calculuswhiz for the tip.
It was a simple fix with adding modulo to the tock function.

```
(define (render x)
  (cond
    [(< (tock x)  RESTART-POINT)
     (place-image cat1 (tock x) Y-cat1 BACKGROUND)]
    [(>= (tock x) RESTART-POINT)
    (place-image cat1 (modulo(tock x)RESTART-POINT) Y-cat1 BACKGROUND)]))
```